# File or Assembly not found when using Assembly.Load(path)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am implementing a ASP.NET MVC 4 application which supports plugins and since today I have a strange behavior and I do not know why:
I load the Plugins via `Assembly.Load(path)` which worked fine a few days ago, but locked my files as shadow copying does not work as the plugin folder was outside `/bin`.
Because of this I used `Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(path))` which also works fine, but I think is not really clean code, so today I moved my plugin folder inside `/bin` and switched back to `Assembly.Load(path)`, but now I get the following exception (Translated as I get it in my locale) when executing my code:

> > Could not load file or assembly "PATH_TO_MY_DLL" or one of its dependencies. The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)

If I switch back to `Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(path))` it works, but why does it not work when loading the file directly anymore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are making a mistake when you changed it back.

`Assembly.Load(string name)` : loads the assembly named "name".

You should use:

```
Assembly.LoadFile(path);
```